# Движение двух объектов (actor) на 1 сцене независимо друг от друга

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
public void create() {

//код

stage = new Stage();

stage.addActor(tank); // оба танка наследуются от 1 класса
stage.addActor(tank2);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

рендер

```
public void render() {
//код
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
stage.draw();
//код
}
```

как сделать так, чтобы каждый actor двигался независимо друг от друга при нажатии на экран? То есть, если они находятся слева и справа экрана, и при нажатии например в центр, нужно чтобы они оба двигались в центр со своих позиций.

При таком коде конечно двигается только tank2.

Stage работает только с первым actor'ом, обработавшим событие первым. Какие методы нужно переопределить, чтобы событие передавалось и второму actor'у? Или какую логику использовать?

P.S аналогичный вопрос, который был задан в списке ниже, был сформулирован немного неправильно, поэтому по сути это другой вопрос, но ответ был полезен для меня, и надеюсь для других.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Движение актеров в определённую точку экрана можно сделать с помощью

```
Actions.moveTo( Gdx.graphic.getWidth() / 2.0, Gdx.graphic.getHeight() / 2.0, 2.0f /**seconds*//*, Interpolation.linear */ );
```

А добавление екшионов к актерам с помощью Container'ов

```
    Container<Actor> tankContainer = new Container<Actor>( tank );
    tankContainer.addAction( Actions.sequence( 
Actions.moveTo( 0, Gdx.graphic.getHeight() / 2.0 ),
Actions.moveTo( Gdx.graphic.getWidth() / 2.0, Gdx.graphic.getHeight() / 2.0, 2.0f /*seconds*//*, Interpolation.linear */ ) );

mStage.addActor( tankContainer );  

Container<Actor> tankContainer_2 = new Container<Actor>( tank_2 );
    tankContainer_2.addAction( Actions.sequence( 
Actions.moveTo( Gdx.graphic.getWidth(), Gdx.graphic.getHeight() / 2.0 ),
Actions.moveTo( Gdx.graphic.getWidth() / 2.0, Gdx.graphic.getHeight() / 2.0, 2.0f /*seconds*//*, Interpolation.linear */ ) );

mStage.addActor( tankContainer_2 );  

в render'е 
mStage.act( delta );  
mStage.draw();
```

И в классе Танка надо использовать для позиции танка при отрисовки методы

```
getX() и getY()
```

А если хочется поворачивать танки, то

```
tankContainer_2.addAction( Actions.rotateBy(...) );
```

и при отрисовки классе Танка можно использовать

```
getRotation()
```

А чтобы отловить нажатие в любом месте экрана можно отнаследоваться от     InputProcessor, и с Gdx.input.setInputProcessor лучше использовать InputMultiplexer

```
InputMultiplexer input = new InputMultiplexer();
input.add( mStage );
input.add( this );
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( input );
```

Comment: Тоже самое. Скорее всего надо разобраться с методом:


    `@Override
    public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
    return this;
    }`